# Add a class attribute to certain links

Tags: javascript, wordpress, language-translation

I have pages on my site that go through a translation proxy. I need the displayed text in certain links to not be translated. I can add `class="notranslate"` to the link and the translator will skip over it no problem. However, I have hundreds of pages created before I implemented the translator and I'll have hundreds more as I keep going along—manually adding the class is not really an option.

The links I'm specifically concerned with are ones whose display text are literal URLs or email addresses. The translator doesn't touch the `href` attributes so the links still work as expected, but the displayed string gets mangled. For instance, in Vietnamese, "organization@domain.com" is displayed as "tổ chức@domain.com," and a link whose display text should be "domain.com/committees" is translated to "domain.com/commitaries."

So I'm looking for a solution that finds `a` elements whose display text contains "@" or "/" and adds `class="notranslate"`. I don't think I need too robust a solution as I otherwise don't use the "@" or "/" in link display text often, if ever, except in these situations. I would guess this could be done with Javascript, but I'm a JS beginner at best. An option that filters content on the backend through Wordpress could also be a nice solution.

Comment: This would HEAVILY depend on the plugin being used.

Comment: @TonyDjukic how so? I can manually add the notranslate class anywhere with no problem. I just want to automate it somehow. I'm using GTranslate for the record.

Comment: The automation part - does the plugin provide some sort of hook or filter?  That's why the part that heavily depends on the plugin in question.  I'm assuming that the `.notranslate` class was something offered by GTranslate, so they may also have an automation process. It also depends on when the translation is made, is it on the fly as the page loads or are translations recorded in the database?  If it's on the fly can you approach it with jQuery?  This all depends  a lot on how the specific plugin goes about doing what it does.

Comment: @TonyDjukic taking a closer look, the plugin actually doesn't do anything except provide the language switcher. It's all handled by a translation proxy. So I can filter the_content via WP with no problem. Or JS is fine too. I think this might just be a question of how to find and replace the specific things I'm looking for in the link display text (still out of my depth on that).

Answer (score 1):

This is simple using jquery, ideally this will need to load before your translations plugin.

Note: If you have jquery already loaded as most wordpress themes already do, then you can remove the first line from this code, which includes the jquery library.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function() {
    
      let text = $(this).text();  
    
      if(text.includes("@")) {
        $(this).addClass('notranslate');
      }

      if(text.includes("/")) {
        $(this).addClass('notranslate');
      }
 
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess this would work on the mailto links, but searching the href attribute for a slash will return pretty much every link on the page. I'm trying to only add the notranslate class when the link display text (i.e. what's in between the <a> tags) contains a slash.

Comment: Ok sure, i have updated the code to check the link text instead of the href. Is this version better?